# overflow situation in records of database table

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We are having a multi-centre client. This client of ours has added 215,314 records in one of our tables from this year only. This has resulted in a situation when loading files sometimes cause the system to stop responding.
I was wondering about if it's a good idea to archieve old data out from that table. the table is not normalized I can assure you and has more than 60 columns (it's an old system) what can we do datbasevise for just making the situation better.

Comment: At first glance, adding 215,314 records is really not much. How much data does on record hold?

Comment: Did not understand when you said "This has resulted in a situation when loading files sometimes cause the system to stop responding."

Answer (score 0):

It may well be a good idea to archive data out of this table. If you do, you would be well advised to make it an automatic process.

But, since this will likely have an effect on your client, you should probably discuss it with them first, rather than us :-)

And, in all honesty, a couple of hundred thousand rows should not really be a problem to a serious DBMS. I suspect there's something else at play here, which you might want to look into (in particular, probably that loading process you refer to).

There are a large number of things that can be done to improve database performance. With a little more information, we could be of much greater service.